# How rotate a part of label in circuitikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border={1mm}]{standalone}

\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to [R,l={{{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$+\;\; v_2\;\; -$}}}}},o-o](0,-3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

But I prefer the following output:

[image]

Comment: You can try to use the standard `v` and the `voltage shift` and other voltage positioning options (see the manual). Otherwise, name the component and put nodes manually near the appropriate anchors... Will write a possible solution tomorrow, if nobody does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all this is still LaTeX, so you can use an array.

```
\documentclass[border={1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to [R,l={{{{$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}+\\ v_2\\ -\end{array}$}}}},o-o](0,-3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]